# Arrows still fall short after removing Quick Shot

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I got that perk but I regretted it and the only way to get rid of it was through the console, which is what I did. But that annoying bug is still there, so now I draw my bow at regular speed only to have half of the arrows drop dead?

I tried restarting the game and reloading, the problem is still there. Is this character doomed forever?

Answer (score 1):

So I found out after using the Bound Bow on a new character that the character in this question was still drawing the bow at a faster speed than usual, even after removing the perk. So I'm guessing the "aftermath" of the perk still exists.

I can't ask for a better reason to prolong the life of this game than to make a new character because of a bug!